# Use column index instead of name in group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to summarize a dataframe with dplyr, like so:

```
> test <-data.frame(ID = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), val = c(1:4))
> test %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarize(av = mean(val))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      ID    av
  <fctr> <dbl>
1      A   1.5
2      B   3.5
```

But suppose that instead of grouping by the column called "ID" I wish to group by the first column, regardless of its name. Is there a simple way to do that?

I've tried a few naive approaches (`group_by(1)`, `group_by(.[1])`, `group_by(., .[1])`, `group_by(names(.)[1])` to no avail. I'm only just beginning to use tidyverse packages so I may be missing something obvious.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618744/dplyr-how-to-reference-columns-by-column-index-rather-than-column-name-using-mu?noredirect=1&lq=1) is very similar, but it's about mutate and I wasn't able to generalize it to my problem. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476410/using-index-to-reference-column-in-summarise-in-dplyr-r?noredirect=1&lq=1) is also similar, but the accepted answer is to use a different package, and I'm trying to stick with dplyr.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use one of the *scoped* variants (`group_by_at`) for this:

```
test %>% group_by_at(1) %>% summarise(av = mean(val))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#      ID    av
#  <fctr> <dbl>
#1      A   1.5
#2      B   3.5
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `across` functionality as of version `1.0.0`:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
  group_by(across(1)) %>% 
  summarise(av = mean(val))
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  ID       av
#  <fct> <dbl>
#1 A       1.5
#2 B       3.5
```

Answer (score 4):

In older versions of `dpylyr`, You could use standard evaluation with `dplyr::group_by_`:

```
test %>% 
 group_by_(names(.)[1]) %>% 
 summarize(av = mean(val))
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#      ID    av
#  <fctr> <dbl>
#1      A   1.5
#2      B   3.5
```

Comment: Standard evaluation is now [deprecated](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/se-deprecated.html).

Answer (score 3):

If we need to use NSE, then `sym` and `!!` can be used

```
test %>%
     group_by(!! rlang::sym(names(.)[1])) %>%
     summarise(av = mean(val))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#      ID    av
#  <fctr> <dbl>
#1      A   1.5
#2      B   3.5
```

We can also create a function.  If we pass quoted strings, then we use `sym` with `!!` or else go for the `enquo/!!` route

```
f1 <- function(dat, grp, valueCol) {
     dat %>%
        group_by(!! rlang::sym(grp)) %>%
        summarise(av = mean(!! rlang::sym(valueCol)))
}

f1(test, "ID", "val")
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#      ID    av
#  <fctr> <dbl>
#1      A   1.5
#2      B   3.5
```

Comment: This is more complicated than I actually need for my problem, but it started me down a fruitful learning path about evaluation and [programming with dplyr](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

Answer (score 0):

As `group_by_at` has now been superseded, it is now better to use either `across` or `pick`.  Use of `across` has already been shown.  For `pick` use this syntax

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
  group_by(pick(1)) %>% 
  summarise(av = mean(val))
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  ID       av
#  <fct> <dbl>
#1 A       1.5
#2 B       3.5
```

More information on this super helpful `pick` can be seen [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pick.html).