# Display weighted.mean of sub-groups with using column index instead of name in group_by_at

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

Sticking to library `dplyr`, I need to calculate weighted average of a variable by subgroups of other variables using column indexes instead of column names. Here is the example:

```
data <- read.table(text = 'obs income education type weight   
                            1   1000      A     blue    10     
                            2   2000      B     yellow   1     
                            3   1500      B     blue     5     
                            4   2000      A     yellow   2 
                            5   3000      B     yellow   2', 
                   header = TRUE)
```

Everything goes well using `group_by`, `weighted.mean` and `mutate` when using column names for grouping:

```
df <-data %>%
     group_by(education,type) %>% 
     mutate(weighted_income = weighted.mean(income, weight))
df
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   education, type [4]
    obs income education type   weight weighted_income
  <int>  <int> <fct>     <fct>   <int>           <dbl>
1     1   1000 A         blue       10           1000.
2     2   2000 B         yellow      1           2667.
3     3   1500 B         blue        5           1500.
4     4   2000 A         yellow      2           2000.
5     5   3000 B         yellow      2           2667.
```

But I need to use column indexes instead of column names. I was able to make  `group_by_at` works but only for 1 group, like this (column 3 = education):

```
df %>%
   group_by_at(3) %>% 
   mutate(weighted_income = weighted.mean(income, weight))
df
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   education [2]
    obs income education type   weight weighted_income
  <int>  <int> <fct>     <fct>   <int>           <dbl>
1     1   1000 A         blue       10           1167.
2     2   2000 B         yellow      1           1938.
3     3   1500 B         blue        5           1938.
4     4   2000 A         yellow      2           1167.
5     5   3000 B         yellow      2           1938.
```

But I get an error for sub-groups (education = column 3, type= column 4)

```
df %>%
   group_by_at(3,4) %>% 
   mutate(weighted_income = weighted.mean(income, weight))

Error: Can't create call to non-callable object
```

How to make this last piece of code work for sub-groups? 
My query is related to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46436506/use-column-index-instead-of-name-in-group-by) on grouping using column indexes rather column names but the answers only refer to groups, not sub-groups.

Comment: You need `c(3, 4)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to concatenate the indexes as without it, the `group_by_at` thinks the '3' as the `.vars` and the 4 as `.funs` based on the usage

> group_by_at(.tbl, .vars, .funs = list(), ..., .add = FALSE)

Therefore, do a concatenation and it would evaluate it for `.vars`

```
data %>% 
   group_by_at(c(3, 4)) %>%
   mutate(weighted_income = weighted.mean(income, weight))
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups: education, type [4]
#    obs income education type   weight weighted_income
#  <int>  <int> <fctr>    <fctr>  <int>           <dbl>
#1     1   1000 A         blue       10            1000
#2     2   2000 B         yellow      1            2667
#3     3   1500 B         blue        5            1500
#4     4   2000 A         yellow      2            2000
#5     5   3000 B         yellow      2            2667
```

Or we can place it inside `vars` to notify that it is the `.vars`

```
data %>%
   group_by_at(vars(3, 4)) %>% 
   mutate(weighted_income = weighted.mean(income, weight))
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups: education, type [4]
#    obs income education type   weight weighted_income
#  <int>  <int> <fctr>    <fctr>  <int>           <dbl>
#1     1   1000 A         blue       10            1000
#2     2   2000 B         yellow      1            2667
#3     3   1500 B         blue        5            1500
#4     4   2000 A         yellow      2            2000
#5     5   3000 B         yellow      2            2667
```

Comment: I noticed only today that while `group_by` and `group_by_at` gives the same result when there is only 1 variable/index, the results are different for repeated groupings. The reason seems to be that, contrarily to `group_by`, `group_by_at()` does not override existing grouping correctly. Adding `ungroup() %>% group_by_at()` solve the problem.

Comment: @Elixterra  There is some bug in that direction.  You are right