# how to group by on column index in dplyr

Tags: r

I have a scenario where I get the column index in a variable and the I have to group by and summarise by that variable

```
 col_index <- which(sapply(dataframe, function(x) any(x == "Area of Maintenance")))

> col_index
  X__7 
  8
```

Now I want to group by `col_index` value like following

```
df%>%
group_by(df[col_index]) %>%
summarise(count = n()) %>%
as.data.frame()
```

It gives me following error.

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
Evaluation error: Column index must be at most 1 if positive, not 8.
```

`col_index` has a dynamic value. How can I do it in r?

Comment: try `group_by_at(col_index)`.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
col_index <- which(sapply(colnames(dataframe), function(x) any(x == "Area of Maintenance")))

df%>%
group_by(.[[col_index]]) %>%
summarise(count = n()) %>%
as.data.frame()
```

**Note:** I had to use `colnames` in `sapply` to get it to correctly work on my machine

**Credit:** I took help from [dplyr: how to reference columns by column index rather than column name using mutate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618744/dplyr-how-to-reference-columns-by-column-index-rather-than-column-name-using-mu)

Answer (score 2):

You can group by all columns that match the given function using `group_by_if`:

```
df %>%
    group_by_if(function(x) any(x == "Area of Maintenance")) %>%
    summarise(count = n()) %>%
    as.data.frame()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but what if I want to do so with `col_index` ? Can we do it this way?